# преобразование числа в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
b = 456; 
c = str(b); 
x = list(c); 
z = str(x); 
a = int(z);
```

почему невозможно преобразовать `int` к типу `list` и обратно в `int`?
логикеа такая, с int превращает в str, с str в list, а потов в обратном направлении

Comment: а как вы представляете себе преобразование списка в число? Возьмите 0 элемент например.

Comment: Думаю для всех очевидно что 0 должен быть пустым списком, а 2 должно быть [1, 0]. :)

Comment: @Arnial А 3 должно быть [2, 1, 0] или [1, 1]?

Comment: что вы ожидаете получить? Приведите явный пример и словами детально опишите

Comment: @Arnial: ещё вариант:  `2 -> [2]`, `456 -> [1, 200]`

Comment: Pero, всё равно непонятно. Вы хотите получить список из цифр числа, записанного в десятичном представлении?

Answer (score 1):

```
z = str(x);
```

Стоит заменить на

```
z = ''.join(x)
```

И что мешает самому написать преобразование?

```
x = 1234

result = []
while x > 0:
    result.append(x % 10)
    x //= 10

result.reverse()
print(result)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]

num = 0
for i, v in enumerate(reversed(result)):
    num += v * 10 ** i
print(num)  # 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы вероятно хотите, чтобы

```
list(456) == [4, 5, 6]
```

и

```
int([4, 5, 6]) == 456
```

Но функция `list()` работает только с объектами, которые имеют интерфейс `iterable`, например с `множествами`, `строками`, `итераторами` и `генераторами` - просто со всем, что может использоваться в цикле `for` перед двоеточием:

```
for i in range(10):
for i in (2, 3, 5):
for i in "abcd":
```

Теоретически бы могло быть по меньшей мере

```
list(любый_объект) == [любый_объект]
```

но ни это не так, потому что бы могли возникнуть проблемы:

```
i = 456
list(i)     # [456] или [i] ?  [456] всегда то самое, но [i] меняется с i
```

---

С другой стороны, функция `int()` не может работать со списками - что разумное можно ожидать например от

```
int(["abc", [3.7, i, (5, 2)], True, (max, 1)])     # ???
```